# Is there any widgets available for `DurationField` in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-widget

I am about to add `DurationField` 's widget for admin site and want duration field's widget for input.

### **Problem statement**

In below `PromoCode` class have `DurationField` namely `duration`. But in admin it shows `TextInput` as input.

```
class PromoCode(models.Model):
    """
    Promo Code model to maintain offers
    """
    code = models.CharField(_("Code"), max_length=60, help_text="Promo code")
    # Validations and constraints for promo code
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start date"), null=True, blank=True, help_text="Start date of promo code offer")
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End date"), null=True, blank=True, help_text="End date of promo code offer")
    duration = models.DurationField(_("Duration"), null=True, blank=True, help_text="Validity period of promo code")
    ...
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class PromoCodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Model admin for promocodes
    """
    list_display = ('code', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date',)
    fields = (
    'code', 'description', 'discount', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'duration', 'sitewide_countdown', 'user_countdown',
    'coin_currencies', 'fiat_currencies',)
```

*Below image is just for reference, `duration` field is not in human readable format.*

[image: Reference image]

### Expected behaviour

> What is the best way to add `DurationField` 's widget into admin form to make it easy to read and edit? Currently it is quite hard for admin to add time duration.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you need: [http://www.columbia.edu/~njn2118/journal/2015/10/30.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Enjn2118/journal/2015/10/30.html)

I would just add that you need to set a custom form in your admin class.

like:

```
from .forms import ModelFormWithDurationWidget

class SnippetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
    form = ModelFormWithDurationWidget
    inlines = [
    SliderInline,
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@pre_save` in the admin and transform duration to the readable format you want.

Comment: Actually I want Form input widget. To handle this duration field